# Unable to make Ms Access form blank to enter new records

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a problem. When I open the Ms Access form to enter new records, it is showing old records. I need it to show a blank form, I have tried me.Refresh, me.Requery and call DoCmd.GoToRecord(,, acNewRec)

What else can i try?

The call DoCmd.GoToRecord(,, acNewRec) line is producing an error: ' a problem occured while Ms Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX control"

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    'me.Requery
    'me.Refresh
    Call DoCmd.GoToRecord(, , acNewRec)
    If Not IsNull(Me.SubjectID) Then
        Forms!Data_Pro_Patient_Entry![my_rep].Visible = True
        Call Disable_Schedule_Generation
    Else
        Forms!Data_Pro_Patient_Entry![my_rep].Visible = False
        Call generate_auto_id
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Either just move to new record row or set form Data Entry property to yes. Don't use parentheses and Call is not needed: `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're opening the form from code,
add "acFormAdd" to data DataMode
like

```
docmd.OpenForm {FormName},acNormal,,,acFormAdd
```

Comment: Note: form name would be within quote marks and braces would be dropped.